# SQL Query to find records belongs to two states

Tags: mysql, sql, hql

| cust_id | state |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | CA |
| 2 | IL |
| 3 | SC |
| 1 | PA |
| 3 | IA |
| 4 | MO |
| 5 | VA |
| 4 | NY |

Can any one please advise on SQL Query that return the cust_id that belong to two states as below:

The output should be

| cust_id | state |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | CA |
| 1 | PA |
| 3 | SC |
| 3 | IA |
| 4 | NY |
| 4 | MO |

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query

Solution 1

```
Select * From yourtable
Where Cust_Id In (Select cust_id From yourtable Group By cust_id Having 
Count(*) = 2) Order By cust_id,state
```

Solution 2

```
With T1 As 
(Select cust_id From yourtable Group By cust_id Having Count(*) = 2) 
Select T2.* From yourtable T2 Join T1 On T1.cust_id = T2.cust_id O 
Order By T2.cust_id,T2.state
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tmp.*
   FROM tmp
 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT cust_id
        ,COUNT(STATE) s_count
    FROM tmp
    GROUP BY [cust_id]
) sub 
ON tmp.cust_id = sub.cust_id
 WHERE sub.s_count = 2
 ORDER BY cust_id
    ,STATE
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach would use a `COUNT` window function, that will assign the amount of times each "*cust_id*" occurs in your table. Once you get this value, you can filter out rows whose count is smaller than 2.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(cust_id) OVER(PARTITION BY cust_id) AS cnt 
    FROM tab
)
SELECT cust_id,
       state
FROM cte 
WHERE cnt > 1
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wSigZxzsjvPTngVwsGEn2H/0).